# Continues to execute MVC-controller after FormsAuthentication.SignOut()

Tags: .net, model-view-controller, session, authentication, controller

I save all session in the database. Lets imagine that this session was lost in the database, not in the cookies.

In OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext) I retrieve user object from database base on the session id.

```
if (HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    //Gets user data from DB.
    var user = userRepos.GetUser(HttpContext.User.Identity.Name); 

        if (user != null)
        {
            CurrentUser = user;
            Thread.CurrentPrincipal = HttpContext.User = new DibPrincipal(user);
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
            Session.Abandon();
            Response.Redirect(FormsAuthentication.LoginUrl, true);
        }
    }
}
```

Imagine that user called a controller GetDocuments, but he was redirected to FormsAuthentication.LoginUrl. It works, user is been redirected, but I get en exception which shows an error in GetDocument controller, because CurrentUser does not exist. So .net trying to call GetDocuments even after redirecting.

How to avoid this error?

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not redirect from your OnAuthorization function but rather set the Result parameter from the filterContext as such :

```
filterContext.Result == new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary {
{
    "controller",
    "Utilisateurs"
},
{
    "action",
    "Connexion"
},
{
    "ReturnUrl",
    filterContext.HttpContext.Request.RawUrl
}
});
```

Comment: It works well! Thank you. But why is it not right to use redirection from OnAuthorization. What is the difference in these two approaches?

Comment: Because you shouldn't manage redirects yourself directly, but rather indicate to mvc that you want to redirect, and therefore allowing it to manage the redirect properly. Your "Response.Redirect" is a bit like stopping the process in the middle of itself.